# Finding the size of the variable without using sizeof()

Tags: c, memory, sizeof

I have this below code:

```
main()
{
    int pt = {0}, *ppt = &pt;
    char *p1 = NULL, *p2 = NULL;

    p1 = (char*)(ppt);
    p2 = (char*)(ppt+1);
    printf("%p\n",p1);
    printf("%p\n",p2);
    printf("%d",(p2-p1));
}
```

This gives me the size of the variable as expected. But I don't
understand how this works. The p1 and p2 as to be char. Why? If I
change that to short or int, I get the result as 1, though the address
has the same difference.

Comment: Read more your C programming books about [pointer arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm)

Comment: what does `int pt = {0}` mean?

Comment: I don't see a reason why p1 and p2 must be char *. Should work with any other type also.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: Same as `int pt = 0;`. The syntax with the redundant pair of `{}` has been in the language since forever. This is why `{ 0 }` is an universal zero initializer in C. You can use `{ 0 }` to initialize anything.

Comment: @claus: you will not get the size unless you switch to char* arithmetic.

Comment: You have to remember that for any pointer `p` and any index `i`that `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p + i)`. That should help explain why the result you get is the difference in *units* and not bytes.

Comment: @Oliver I dont understand. ppt will give me back the memory address of the int pt. Just for example lets say this is 0x00000000. (ppt+1) will give me back the memory address from ppt + one int (for 32bit int) this will be 0x00000004. Therefor it is totally similar if I cast the address to p1 = (long*)(ppt) oder p1=(long long *). The values will always be 0x00000000 and 0x00000004 because *p1 and *p2 will always be a pointer regardingless of which type. So p2-p1 will always be 4 whatever p1 or p2 are defined as.

Comment: @Claus Bönnhoff: "... will always be 4 whatever p1 or p2 are defined as" - that's false. One more time: you need to read about pointer arithmetic in C. In C pointer arithmetic takes into account pointer type. It works in therms of pointed type size. If the pointed type has size `4`, then `0x4 - 0x0` will produce `1`, not `4`. The absolute difference between addresses is automatically *divided* by the pointed type size. This is why we always use `char *` (since `char` always has size `1`) for raw pointer arithmetic.

Comment: I'm embarrassed. Perhaps I should not try to answer questions directly coming home from a 3 day developer conference. Sorry Claus

Comment: @AndreyT Please make the reply to clause as the answer. The point that address is automatically divided by the pointed type size helped :) which really says why it has to be a char Thanks :)

Comment: @Xavier Geoffrey: It is no longer possible to reply to your question since it is marked as duplicate. I think the answer at the duplicate link are sufficiently clear in this.

Comment: @AndreyT oh ok...but still i couldn't understand before i read your answer...